# aLogCat not showing the log for my app

Tags: android, logcat

I am trying to capture the log from my application using the aLogCat program. The program only capture the system log, but not from my application.
I have also tried with catlog, but I got the same issue.

Any idea?

Best regards,

Comment: Capturing logs of other apps is blocked in recent Android releases.

Comment: Try to restart eclipse. Sometimes it's the way out to me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Third-party apps, like the ones that you cite, [can only see their own log statements as of Android 4.1](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/07/12/read-logs-regression.html), as they can no longer hold the `READ_LOGS` permission.